# iOS App Name doesn't appear

Tags: ios, xcode

`App name` doesn't appear under the `app icon` both in simulator and in device. Need your suggestion about what might be wrong.

Following are the things I have checked:

- Went to `[Project Name].plist` and found a key: Bundle name with value: ${PRODUCT_NAME}
- Clicked on Project Name and Name is correct in File Inspector's Name field

Comment: Set bundle display name in info.plist file as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application info.plist is use to set the application bundle display name `CFBundleDisplayName`
like or if you want to give custom name then change `${PRODUCT_NAME}` string

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using Xcode 5.

Go to your target settings and select Info from the top tabs.

Your app display name should be under a key called "Bundle Display Name"

Comment: Your answer is also right and was very timely. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Targets in Xcode

"Build setting" on your project's target 
Search for "Product Name" under "Packaging". Change the value of that what you want the new program name is going to be.